# Could not open library "pHash.dll"

Tags: ruby, phash

This is my first time using Ruby. Currently I am trying to run [this](https://github.com/HackerLabs/PhotoOrganizer) Ruby script on Windows. I have downloaded an extracted this to `c:/PhotoOrganizer-master`

It also requires [pHash](http://www.phash.org/download/) so I have downloaded and extracted (to `c:/pHash`).

I have set the following environment variable:

`PHASH_LIB = c:/pHash/Release`

Currently when I run the script (`ruby PhotoOrganizer`) I get the following error:

```
C:/Ruby200-x64/.../ffi/library.rb:133:in
`block in ffi_lib': Could not open library 'C:\pHash\Release\pHash.dll':  
(LoadError)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @Nakilon it can be completely relevant since there are people who might be using old versions of ruby.